# Single Sign On using salesforce and openam

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, federated-identity, openam

Hii I am new to salesforce and also to openam, can some one please tell me how to start up with and detail implementation of single sign (both SP & IDP initiated) using salesforce as SP and openam as IDP

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at ...

http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/admin-guide/index/chap-federation.html#salesforce-as-sp

?
Of course making yourself familiar with SAML2.0 spec will help a lot.

Comment: Hi, vielen Dank Bernhard. I have gone through the link and was able to configure SSO using salesforce and openam. The steps i have followed is http://nrsfgroup.blogspot.in/2013/08/single-sign-on-using-openamidp-and.html . Once everything is done and i enter domian url of my service provider it is redirecting to openam's login page and when i login with a particular user, its not redirecting back to salesforce instead its showing that particular user details in openam. so can u please help me on this